# sql max on a column

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
id  |  sequence | name | status...
1         0       name1   A
2         1       name1   A
3         2       name1   A
4         0       name2   I
5         0       name3   I
```

the query does not take the name column such that, select * from table where status = 'A'

what I want is to get only the max sequence like this.

```
id  |  sequence | name | status..
3         2       name1   A
```

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY sequence DESC LIMIT 1`

or

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE sequence=(SELECT MAX(sequence) FROM table)`

Comment: with this query, I am getting the largest value(MAX) of all the rows, not just with name1.